# Can I have multiple versions of Microsoft Office installed?

Tags: microsoft-office, version

Is it possible to have multiple versions of office installed on the same machine without use of a VM?  i.e. Office 2003 and Office 2007?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Information about using 2007 Office suites and programs on a computer that is running another version of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928091/en-us)

> You can install and use more than one
>   version of Microsoft Office on a
>   single computer. For example, you can
>   install and use both Microsoft 2007
>   Office suites and programs and
>   Microsoft Office 2003 on the same
>   computer. However, we do not recommend
>   this.

Comment: I've seen people run into problems with Outlook - the rest of the suite worked okay, but Outlook flipped out and refused to co-operate.  (It wasn't my machine, so I'm a little fuzzy on the precise scenario.)

Comment: The distilled answer from that article is the "Repair Office" menu item.

Comment: All programs except Outlook work OK. Outlook runs a driver called MAPI, of which there can only be one version on a system at a time. Also, choose which version of office you want to be default and install that version last AFTER completely installing and COMPLETELY patching the non-default version. Then don't install any further patches to the non-default version, or else your preferences will be messed up. See this question for further discussion of this: http://superuser.com/questions/192468/multiple-version-of-excel/315509

Comment: It works OK with Word on my PC, but whenever I switch versions some installation process starts (it does not require any media or so, but takes a while and is annoying) and takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

I did it for programming purposes (having the interop libraries) and it works. That said, I only installed MS WORD and MS EXCEL (and access from Office XP)

But it works.